# JPA in clause in query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have a class Api which contains a list of data:

```
public class Api {
    private String id;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Data> datas; 
}
```

I have a ApiRepository extending crud repository where I have defined a query:

```
@Query(value="select api from Api api where :data in (api.datas)")
public List<Api> getDatas(@Param("data") data)
```

I get this error when executing the query:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
>   could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1

Comment: If you are using log4j then enable below property and this will help you to print the SQL. So you find the where the syntax error.`log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the use parenthesis `(api.datas)` from your query :

```
@Query(value="select api from Api api where :data in api.datas")
```

You can use parenthesis in case you have multiples values for example :

```
select api from Api api where :data in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```